# Cakephp i18n translation formatter U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

In Cakephp 2, I was using this [repo](https://github.com/cakephp/localized) for cake.po translations. But it seems like it isn't not updated for Cakephp 3. So I runned i18n shell as noted [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html#generating-pot-files) and created `cake.pot` file. Then I made some of translations and added `cake.po` files into the folder `src\Locale\`.

When the msgstr part is empty, `timeAgoInWords` shows English words, if translation found, cakephp shows translated version.

But this doesn't work for Arabic language. Other languages works well.

In cakephp 3 while making a `timeAgoInWords` like this:

```
$string = $this->Time->timeAgoInWords(1338659672, array('end' => '+10 year'));
```

I get this error: `Error: [Aura\Intl\Exception\CannotInstantiateFormatter] msgfmt_create: message formatter creation failed: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR`

Error stack:

```
Error: [Aura\Intl\Exception\CannotInstantiateFormatter] msgfmt_create: message formatter creation failed: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
Request URL: /ar/tools/
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php(71): Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter->_formatMessage('ar', NULL, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/aura/intl/src/Aura/Intl/Translator.php(142): Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter->format('ar', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php(110): Aura\Intl\Translator->translate('{0} years', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Time.php(384): __dn('cake', '{0} year', '{0} years', 3, 3)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/src/Template/Tools/index.ctp(62): Cake\I18n\Time->timeAgoInWords(Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(833): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(793): Cake\View\View->_evaluate('/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(464): Cake\View\View->_render('/var/www/vhosts...')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(582): Cake\View\View->render(NULL, NULL)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(120): Cake\Controller\Controller->render()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\ToolsController))
#11 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#12 {main}

Notice: Notice (8): Undefined offset: 3 in [/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php, line 68]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 138
Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter::format() - CORE/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php, line 68
Aura\Intl\Translator::translate() - ROOT/vendor/aura/intl/src/Aura/Intl/Translator.php, line 142
__dn - CORE/src/I18n/functions.php, line 110
Cake\I18n\Time::timeAgoInWords() - CORE/src/I18n/Time.php, line 384
include - APP/Template/Tools/index.ctp, line 62
Cake\View\View::_evaluate() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 833
Cake\View\View::_render() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 793
Cake\View\View::render() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 464
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 582
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 120
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

Edit: I get very similar error for Russian language. When I remove `src\Locale\ru\cake.po` file, I get `U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR` again. Note that Russian has 3 plural form, while English and other languages have 2 plural forms.

Comment: This seems to stem from your translations, so it would be useful if you'd show them! Seeing the undefined offset error, you're probably lacking the third plural form (and consequently others too). I'm not familiar with Arabic, but from **http://localization-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html** it looks like it has 6 forms!?

Comment: Thank for reply. Yes, Arabic has 6 plural forms. But in Cakephp 2 when there is no equivalent plural form in cake.po, or there is no cake.po for Arabic language, English version was shown. But it seems like Cakephp 3 doesn't fallback for Arabaic language, but can fallback for other languages ? Because other languages has 2 plural forms. Is it like that?.

Comment: How does your translation file look like?

Comment: I created cake.pot file by using bake shell. Renamed it as cake.po. This also created same error. I removed cake.po and same error exists. Doesn't cakephp fallback to English version of string when there is no equivalent cake.po file for that language ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Russian cake.po translated by me. When I get it from https://github.com/cakephp/localized/blob/master/src/Locale/ru/cake.po it works fine.